# Pandas Dataframes, Calculating row to row delta without looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3E54.png)I have a pandas dataframe, I want to populate a column with the delta between two rows.
Each row is a day and I need the day to day change.
I've accomplished this in the past by looping through the rows.
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
Col1   Col2
10
13       3
11      -2
 8      -3
12       5
```

[dataframe]

Comment: `df['col2'] = df['col1'].diff()`.

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: Yeah, that does it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.Dataframe.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). Here is a [great article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) explaining the speedups involved with different Pandas operations for iterating through rows of a Dataframe (hint: avoid loops whenever possible).